# How to setup libGDX project only for Android & iOS?

Tags: android, ios, libgdx, game-engine

i have developed some applications on android.But now i want to learn game development in Android & iOS with libGDX.
I want to only develop for Android & iPhone.I do not want a desktop project.
All tutorials tell me to first create desktop project than write code in main project & than run as Android application.
But i want to write code in android project using both android & libGDX features.
is this possible ?
if yes than how ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for you to multi-target with LibGDX, you need to use the core project for shared code, and the starter project for each platform you are targeting (the desktop target is not required if you don't intend to do desktop). If you want to use platform specific code, typically that would be done through an interface (see https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ApplicationPlatformSpecific).

If you want to only target a single platform and not use a shared project, you can can create a single project for that platform then add the appropriate jars and other resources. I think this makes more sense for Desktop only or Android only as the iOS stuff is less straightforward to set up.

Comment: can all the APIs and classes and all other features of Android accessible from main project ?

Comment: No, not by default, as that would break multi-targeting. You could not target both Android and iOS (or any other platform) if you used Android specific stuff from the main project. This is why platform specific stuff should be done via interface. What in the Android API do you need to access?

Comment: i am going to make a game like 2D-ARCHERY for Android,iOS & Windows with world-wide scoreloop & in-purchase enabled.
but right no i am not worried about windows & iOS.I have all knowledge of android but i don't know anything about iOS & Windows.

will this be possible with libGDX ?
if yes than please give me some guidelines....!!

Thank  you.

Comment: This is possible with LibGDX. Since your implementation will be different for Android, and iOS (and eventually Windows, maybe) you definitely want to keep the platform specific code in the respective platform project. The link in my answer shows how you can do that. In your main project, define an interface for interacting with leaderboards and purchasing. Then, in each platform project, implement that interface. You just need to pass the implementation into the main project (generally in your game/applicationlistener constructor) and use it as necessary.